# mockito verifying polymorphic methods

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to verify call to a polymorphic method using mockito, and am confused about what the best way forward is.

Example Class

```
public class Library {
    public boolean foo() {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean foo(String s) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean foo(Integer s) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The test class using mockito(ignore the fact that in `LibraryTest` class, `Library` is not the class-under-test, but rather I'm mocking it)

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
public class LibraryTest {
    @Test public void testFoo1() {
        Library mockLibrary = mock(Library.class);
        mockLibrary.foo("Hi");
        verify(mockLibrary).foo(any());
    }
    @Test public void testFoo2() {
        Library mockLibrary = mock(Library.class);
        verify(mockLibrary, never()).foo(any());
    }
}
```

So both the verify statements don't compile, with the error "The method foo(String) is ambiguous for the type Library".

The error kind of makes sense, `any()` tries to return a captor based on the type of the argument but the argument could be `Integer` or `String` or `void`.

What I want to achieve is that in both the tests, a call to any of the `foo` methods is counted by the `verify`. In other words the first `verify` call should succeed if I called any of the `foo` methods and the second `verify` should fail if I call any of the `foo` methods.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: verify(mockLibrary, never()).foo(any()); - Be more specific to this line any() means any type in Java and Mockito is not ale to find differnce among the two methods with different types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use isA matcher

```
verify(mockLibrary).foo(isA(Integer.class));

verify(mockLibrary).foo(isA(String.class));
```

and btw use Mockito.spy instead of Mockito.mock when you only want to see if some methods have been called on the class under test

EDIT with example (written in few minutes, don't mind the code:)) based on the new op details.

```
public static class Library {
    public boolean foo() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean foo(String s) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean foo(Integer s) {
        return true;
    }

    public String x(){
        return "";
    }

    public void y(){
        return;
    }
}


public static class ResponseProvider {
    public boolean result;
}

@Test
public void testFoo1() {
    final ResponseProvider provider = new ResponseProvider();
    provider.result = false;
    Library lib = Mockito.mock(Library.class, new Answer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            if ((invocation.getMethod().getName().equals("foo"))) {
                provider.result = true;
                return true;
            }
            return invocation.callRealMethod();
        }
    });

    //lib.foo();
    //lib.x();
    //lib.y();
    assertTrue(provider.result);

}
```

Comment: the isA(Object.class) didn't work. Also maybe I was not clear. I want to be able to verify a call to foo() also, and my real scenario also includes polymorphed method with 2/3/4 arguments.

Comment: do you want to verify that only one of the polymorphic methods have been called, no matter which exactly?

Comment: yes exactly. and in the second case, that non of the methods got called.

Comment: Uh okay I don't have an exact answer for that, a 'workaround' would be to configure mockito to throw a runtime exception every time one of the foo methods is called and then just verify if the exception has been thrown or not  to cover both scenarios, this is of course only feasible if you only want to test if the methods have been called, if you want to test what's happening inside the methods too that involves a more tricky approach, but still, should be feasible

Comment: @Spundun Iv'e added an example that should cover both your cases and it's not that dirty

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That seems like that might work. What would happen to other calls to that mock object? e.g. if Library had a method called bar, baz... etc, which I didn't want to deal with and let mockito do the default behavior?

Comment: Glad it helped, I've updated the code to work with different methods, the invokation now forwards the calls to the real methods when the method name is different from"foo"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You are mocking the same class which you are testing. Thats not advisable but still

Its giving this exception because mockito doesn't know which method you are verifying among the foo methods. If you want to make sure the method you invoked is called with the right value, you can either use `isA(ClassName)` matcher or use can use ArgumentCaptor.

Example of ArgumentCaptor

```
@Test public void testFoo1() {
    Library mockLibrary = mock(Library.class);
    mockLibrary.foo("Hi");
    ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

    verify(mockLibrary).foo(stringCaptor.capture());
    String actualArgument = stringCaptor.getValue();

    assertEquals(actualArgument, "Hi");
}
```

Comment: In my question I wrote to ignore the fact that I'm mocking it in it's test class, it's just a mockito test really. And maybe I was not clear. I want to be able to verify a call to foo() also, and my real scenario also includes polymorphed method with 2/3/4 arguments.